# AngularJS - Empty <option> - Other solutions not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get rid of this empty <option> in my <select>. I've read a number of other questions about this, but none of them seem to be helping me. Can anybody help me get rid of the empty <option> in this fiddle? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/4CYkd/

js

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.club = {'1':{name:'club name!'}};
    $scope.data.admin = [{related_id:'1',related_table:'club'}]

    //$scope.admin_idx = 0;
}​
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
<select ng-model="admin_idx">
    <option ng-repeat="admin in data.admin" value="{{$index}}">
        {{data[admin.related_table][admin.related_id].name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not combine all your data into a single array of objects and ng-options on that? You wouldn't even need $index at all. I mean objects that have name, related_id and related_table in them.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

http://jsfiddle.net/4CYkd/1/

```
<select ng-model="admin_idx"
        ng-options="$index as data[admin.related_table][admin.related_id].name for admin in data.admin">
</select>
```

hope this helps

Comment: While this does work in the fiddle, it does not in my dev environment. The code seems exactly the same, but obviously something is different. I'll look at it and post more tonight. Thanks.

By the way, what's the functional difference that made this work? Does ng-options handle the empty <option> correctly, and <option ng-repeat...> does not?

Comment: I do not know what the difference is. Perhaps select directive handles ng-options differently than just having ng-repeat in <option> tag. The documentation explicitly says that ng-options should be used instead of <option ng-repeat>.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize I could use $index in ng-options, that's why I had gone with ng-repeat.

Comment: I think the thing is, with ng-options you can also provide a single `<option>` element as the unselected value, or not. You have the choice. If you're just doing all `<option>` elements, there's no way to specify if you want that "prompting" option or not, so it has to assume you do. `ng-options` is better anyway because you can have the values be arbitrary objects instead of just strings.